# How to lets-encrypt several virtual servers on apache

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt

I host several instances of the same ruby on rails application via passenger on an Apache server. In the past these applications have been made available via separate Domains. But 
now I received a domain and several sub-branches from our IT department and I have to serve the applications in the following way:

```
domain.example.de/app_one
domain.example.de/app_two
....
```

While this works nicely without lets-encrypt (just have to configure apache and the ruby on rails applicatons that way). I want to have the pages delivered via https (lets-encrypt) as before. I configured Apache that way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://domain.example.de/app_one

    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app_one/public

    PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/wrappers/ruby

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/app_one/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.example.de/app_one
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

But when calling

```
sudo certbot --apache
```

It does not list out that new "ServerNames" to issue certificates for. If I call certbot with the "-d" flag and provide the "ServerName" manually then I get an error that the domain name contains invalid characters.

Is it possible to issue a certificate for each application in that way? Or do I have to issue one for the domain and use it for every app under that domain then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://domain.example.de/app_one` is not a valid domain name. The domain portion of that is `domain.example.de`. This is what you should use in the `ServerName` directive, and in certbot. Everything else is configured elsewhere.

`/app_one` can be configured in a `<Location>` block or as a reverse proxy, `http://` is already implied by the `:80` part in your `<VirtualHost>`

Regarding certbot, the `--apache` parameter only tells it to use Apache to handle the verification. You still need to provide the domain with the `-d` parameter.